# How to force redirect a subdomain to 'https://www.'?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to redirect

1. `http://sub.domain.com`

and

2. `http://www.sub.domain.com`

and

3. `https://sub.domain.com`

to

- `https://www.sub.domain.com`

How to do this in .htaccess?
Thanks in advance.

and an extra question, where can I learn these? Is it necessary ton learn them?

[You could tell that there are lots of answers in the web, but most of them are for main domain, not for subdomains.]

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect sub.domain.com to https://www.sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# Redirect http://www.sub.domain.com to https://www.sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

You can learn the Apache configuration format here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, yes. Actually I forgot to add that in question. Please edit your code fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will you please tell me the divided version of the code one of which will redirect to https and another will redirect to www? This is for using the code on different subdomains

Comment: I added that in my answer